# i working with connectionist bench (sonar mines vs. rocks) dataset to classify the object if mines oor rock

Tags: python, dataset, raw

i have question about this dataset connectionist bench (sonar mines vs. rocks)
is it raw data or processed data?

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/user/Downloads/sonar.all-data.csv', header=None)
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/connectionist+bench+(sonar,+mines+vs.+rocks)